# Change billing information order Company name to be first

Tags: magento-1.9, address, billing

I want to get the company name up to the first place (see image) for the delivery address at the email that comes after buying something. Do anyone of you guys know where I can find the file for this? im using magento 1.9.2

[image: first]

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it just for other that come after me

[image: solution]